# Indexing SVG files with SOLR

Tags: svg, solr

I am new to Solr, but I suppose that there is an easy way to index SVG files with Solr. I have installed Solr 6.3.0 and I am using an example 'files' core. It works well, but it seems that it parses the SVG files as plain text.

Is there an easy way to take only the texts between the **text** tags?

Ideally, I want to combine some meta data from a JSON file with the text from the SVG files. The JSON file looks like:

```
{
  "id":"000001",
  "title":"Some diagram",
  ...
} ...
```

The associated svg file is 000001.svg.

Is there a way to create a scheme in Solr, that can take the fields from the json and merge a field with the text from the SVG file?

Comment: I think there isn't any way...you need to do these merging things before you pass the file to solr...But lets wait for the others to respond on the same...

Answer (score 0):

The most flexible way that will do what you want is to write a custom indexing utility that parses your JSON, picks up the SVG and extracts the relevant elements, then submits the complete structure to Solr. Depending on your programming language of choice you'll do this with something like SolrJ, Solrnet or another client library.

This is way more flexible and maintainable than integrating it directly into Solr, but if you want to do custom SVG indexing (without the additional JSON), you could use the [XSLT support](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Uploading+Data+with+Index+Handlers#UploadingDatawithIndexHandlers-UsingXSLTtoTransformXMLIndexUpdates) in the regular update handler, or using [an XPathEntityProcessor](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Uploading+Structured+Data+Store+Data+with+the+Data+Import+Handler#UploadingStructuredDataStoreDatawiththeDataImportHandler-DataSources) in a DataImportHandler configuration.

My choice would be the custom indexing code.